# Data not getting into the variable. how to pass id in destroy method

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-views

> how to pass id in a destroy method in modelviewset
>
> model

```py
class Matchscore(TimeStampedModel):
    gameevent = models.ForeignKey(GameEvent, null=True, related_name='game_event',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    match_round = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    team_a = models.ForeignKey(Team,null=True,related_name='team_one',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    team_a_score = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    team_b = models.ForeignKey(Team,null=True,related_name='team_two',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    team_b_score = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    team_won = models.ForeignKey(Team,null=True,related_name='team', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

> modelviewset

```py
class MatchscoreViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication, JWTAuthentication)
    queryset = Matchscore.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MatchScoreSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    
    def destroy(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("delete")
        match = Matchscore.objects.filter().order_by('match_round').first()
        print(match)
        if match :
            match.delete()
            response=({"result":"successfully removed"})
        else:
            response=({"result":"can't delete this round"})
        return Response(response)
```

> how can i pass the id in destroy function in modelviewset, in this format of code i didnt get the data .only when i can satisfy the condition while getting the data in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using routers for this viewset, then you have `pk` arg in your URL by default.

You can probably find it in `kwargs`.

beside that, implemented `destroy` method in `ModelViewSet` can handle all of these for you

Comment: i did'nt understand

Comment: will you plz explain with example

Comment: delete function is working but my condition not satisfying, why?

Comment: can help please